# How to get one line at a time from eloquent query in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

Say I have a simple query to get all rows from a table:

```
App::make('My_Model')->get();
```

But, I have a huge number of rows - say 100,000, so many that PHP runs out of memory trying to read them all in.

For some reason I want to go through each of these rows, and do some operation based on them.

Is there any way to tell laravel to give me one row at a time, the way the old mysql_fetch_row worked?

Note: I'm currently solving this by using limit() commands to get 5000 rows at once, which works fine, except that it repeats the query 20 times.

**I want to know if there is any built in method in laravel or eloquent to give me the next row, instead of all rows ?**

Answer (score 8):

For anybody landing here using Laravel 5.2+ (like I did) There is now a 'cursor' method available which returns a Generator

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_cursor

So instead of ->get() use ->cursor()

Comment: Just to further clarify this, `::cursor()` is a Builder method, not a Model method. To fetch every row from a table using a cursor, your code should look something like this: `foreach (MyModel::query()->cursor() as $stdClass) { /* do something */ }`. Note that you won't get MyModel objects here; rather you'll get instances of `\StdClass`.

Comment: At least in Laravel 8, you get an instance of the model instead of a stdClass object.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to process them, a thousand at a time say, the `chunk()` method in `Eloquent` should work for you:

```
My_Model::chunk(1000, function($my_models)
{
    foreach ($my_models as $my_model)
    {
        // do something
    }
});
```

More in the [Eloquent docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Depends on what you are doing to your data...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, what is the next row in an application that lives shortly? Unless you are building a command line application that has a cursor, you application lives just for a request. Laravel can give you ways to get a subset of your cursor, so if you need 5000 lines, you can get those 5000 lines at the same time.

So you can use paginate:

```
$someUsers = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->paginate(5000);
```

Take and skip:

```
$page = 5;

$pageSize = 5000;

$users = User::skip($page * $pageSize)->take($pageSize)->get();
```

Chunk, internally uses paginagion, but it's a little bit restricting, because it will force you to process your whole cursor:

```
User::chunk(5000, function($users)
{
    /// every time this clojure is ran you get a new subset of 5000 rows.

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        // do whatever you need with them
    }
});
```

Sidenote: you can save memory by turning query log off:

```
DB::disableQueryLog();
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of operation are you trying to perform?  The way you describe it you are loading all 100,000 records into active memory, but there is almost no reason you should need to do that unless you actually want to display all 100,000 records.

- If you want to change some but not all of the records it should be possible to build an DB::update() query to do it, so you don't need to load the records into PHP's memory at all
- If you want to only display certain records it should be possible to modify your $model query so you only load the records into PHP's memory that you actually need.
- If you need to actually display the whole recordset, then you will in fact need to iterate through them piecemeal, but that doesn't sound like what you're trying to do.

Give us more information, what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to iterate through them piecemeal. I can't find the laravel method for iterating over a query result without loading the whole thing into memory, which is what I'm asking about.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand >why< you want to iterate through them piecemeal, as I'm having trouble envisioning an objective for doing so that wouldn't be achieved more easily with a different technique.

Comment: Example use cases: generating a csv file, sending to a mailing list, statistical analysis... there are plenty. You are correct, anything that might be an objective could more easily be done another way, but sometimes implementation choice can be made by a non-tech-savy boss, and we poor devs just have to deal with it as best we can.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point now, particularly the CSV file case.  The difficulty is that you're essentially asking "how do I issue a single SQL query but get the SQL server to hold the results in memory so I can iterate through them without loading the whole result set into PHP?"  I'm doubtful that's possible, but it certainly doesn't seem like something Laravel is built to do out of the box.  I think the 5000-records-at-a-time approach you're using is your best bet.

Comment: The core php functions can do it - e.g. mysql_fetch_assoc only loads a single row, so a loop over mysql_fetch_assoc would allow any number of rows to be processed without running out of memory. However, that's deprecated now, so I need to use the ORM.